# Filename globbing Windows vs. Unix

Tags: windows, unix, batch-file, glob, filepattern

Is something like this possible in the Windows standard shell using wildcards only?

```
$ ls -1 003[5,8]0
00350
00380
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the standard windows command shell (cmd.exe). It understands only the ? and * wildcards; no regular expressions.

Do you have the option of installing Cygwin, Windows Powershell, or another enhanced shell?

Comment: Unfortunately im not able to install any other shells, since this is a production environment and i dont have rights to do so

Comment: I don't think thats strictly true. You could do a regex with `findstr` with the input from a piped `dir` command, I'm not sure how to write it, but I think it should be possible. I'm sure @dbenham or @jeb will be able to come up with something :)

Comment: Fair enough. If you just want the text output and not any side effects from the command, then `dir | findstr /r "003[5,8]0"` will work.

Comment: I will accept this answer, because there is no native way in windows... only by using other commands, which is not an option in my case

Comment: I tried this hack of @Simbilis but there was no result in the cmd.exe output nor anything new in my working directory.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can. Not with a single command, but with a combination of `FOR` and `IF`. Try this to get you started...

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (003?0) do (
  set fn=%%a
  set fnl=!fn:~3,1!
  if .!fnl!==.5 (
    echo !fn!
  )
  if .!fnl!==.8 (
    echo !fn!
  )
)
```